# Flask/Jinja - Display database contents with a command instead of on page load

Tags: python, mysql, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I followed this tutorial to set up a Chat server in Flask (Python 3) that stores the chat history in a MySQL database:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pigpDSOBNMc

I ended up with the following for **main.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecret'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root@127.0.0.1/chat_db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class History(db.Model): # Call 'History' table from 'chat_db' database
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True) # Define 'id' column
    name = db.Column('name', db.String(500)) # Define 'name' column
    message = db.Column('message', db.String(500)) # Define 'message' column

@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(name, msg): # Pass 'name' & 'msg' from the socket
    print('Message: ' + msg) # Print the message to terminal

    message = History(name=name, message=msg) # create 'message' variable where 'message'...
    # ...in 'message=msg' is the 'message' column in the 'History' table...
    # ...and the 'msg' in 'message=msg' is the passed-in 'msg' variable from the socket.
    db.session.add(message) # Add 'message' from the client...
    db.session.commit() # ... and commit (save) the message to the database.

    send(command(name, msg), broadcast=True) # Broadcast the message (display on the web page)

def command(name, msg):
    send_back = ""
    if (msg == "/load-history"):
        send_back = "Command recognized"
    else:
        send_back = "<b>"+name+"</b>"+': '+msg # Broadcast the message (display on the web page))
    return send_back

@app.route('/')
def index():
    messages = History.query.all() # Query all rows from chat 'History' table
    return render_template('index.html', messages=messages)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

and the following for **templates/index.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Chat Room</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.8/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000');
    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
        $("#messages").append('<li>'+msg+'</li>');
        console.log('Received message');
    });
    $('#sendbutton').on('click', function() {
        socket.send($('#myName').val(), $('#myMessage').val());
        $('#myMessage').val('');
    });
});
</script>
<ul id="messages" style="list-style: none;">
    {% for msg in messages %}
        <li>{{ ': '+msg.message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
<input type="text" id="myName" placeholder="Username">
<input type="text" id="myMessage" placeholder="Message">
<button id="sendbutton">Send</button>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks like this:
[image]

Right now, the entire `History` table of chat history is loaded on page-load from this portion of **main.py**:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    messages = History.query.all() # Query all rows from chat 'History' table
    return render_template('index.html', messages=messages)
```

**How could I change my code so the command `/load-history` had to be entered in the "Message" textbox  in order to display the chat history, instead of showing it all on page-load?**

Answer (score 1):

Your message contains "**name** : **message**"

So you are testing if the message is /load-history but in fact, your message is always prefixed by "**name : **"

This is because your send your message like usinng socketio in JS:

```
socket.send($('#myName').val()+': '+$('#myMessage').val());
```

You should send message AND name in 2 different variables and modify your python code to accept this

```
@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(name, msg):

    message = History(name=name, message=msg)
    db.session.add(message)
    db.session.commit()

    send(msg, broadcast=True)
```

And the js:

```
socket.send($('#myName').val(), $('#myMessage').val());
```

Comment: Thank you! Code updated. That was very helpful. I'm still not sure how to load the `History` table with a command instead of loading it on page-load, but I think I'll just stick with loading the `History` table on page-load. Just one last thing: Do you know how to reference `name` in `<li>{{ msg.message }}</li>`? I tried `<li>{{ msg.name+msg.message}}</li>` but get the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'`

Comment: Well, it works after I escaped the variables: `<li>{{ msg.name|e+': '+msg.message|e }}</li>`

Comment: Happy it helps you :) Please marked the answer as resolved